# Angular observable's mapping function

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I work on an Angular project and I try to debug this code :

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  private testsListUrl = "/api/test/list"; // [{testName: 'test1', testStatus: 'OK'}, {testName: 'test2', testStatus: 'OK'}]

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
  }

  public getTests(): Observable<Test[]> {
    return this._http.get(this.testsListUrl).map(this.mapTests);
  }

  private mapTests(response:Response): Test[]{
    return response.json().map(this.mapTest);
  }

  private mapTest(response:Test): Test{
    return {
      name: response.testName,
      status: response.testStatus
    };
  }

}
```

The `getTests()` function seems to work, I get a HTTP answer with `[{testName: 'test1', testStatus: 'OK'}, {testName: 'test2', testStatus: 'OK'}]`.

Then, I map my `Response` to an array of `Test` with `mapTests()`.

Then, I map each element of the json array to a `Test` with `mapTest()`.

But this code does not work. When I log function calls, I enter in `mapTests` but not in `mapTest`.

I partially solved my problem by *inlining* my `mapTest()` call in `mapTests()` like this :

```
private mapTests(response:Response): Test[]{
    return response.json().map(response => ({
        name: response.testName, 
        status: response.testStatus
    }));
}
```

But I don't understand what's going on... Why do I need to *inline* `mapTest()` in `mapTests()` and not `mapTests()` in `getTests()` ?

Comment: Because `this` in `mapTests` isn't what you think it is. You need e.g. `.map(this.mapTests.bind(this))` or `.map(res => this.mapTests(res))`.

Comment: That works. But that means `this` doesn't correspond to the current instance of my `TestService` ?

Comment: Not unless you bind it, either explicitly or with an arrow function, no.

Comment: So what `this` refers to in my first code ?

Comment: Log it out and see!

Comment: When I `console.log(this)` in `mapTests()`, I get my `TestService` as expected, so I still don't understand what's wrong.